# Want to get cursor position within textInput

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am using textInput within grid using rendrer. I am populating a suggestion box just below the text input field on the basis of typed character and index of text input.Problem is that if i shrink grid column then suggestion box is not populating at the right place so I want global position of cursor in the text input field .

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
var inputTxt : TextInput = new TextInput;

var x : Number = inputTxt.cursorManager.currentCursorXOffset;

var y : Number = inputTxt.cursorManager.currentCursorYOffset;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'global coordinate'.
This might resolve your problem.

Comment: Thank you Ashine for answering. I already used global position but it not working because global coordinate are respected to grid not with particular column(text input field).Have you any other solution?